# How to calculate time using QT timer class

Tags: c++, qt, timer

Calculating Time using QT Timer class and display in QT label real-time

Comment: A good start would be to write some code.

Comment: @user3812696 The knowledge to even start is to google "qt timer". You have not done that. SO is not an internet search service. Before you even consider asking here, you should have googled.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `QTimer` class.

Connect timeout signal to slot where you will process data.

In constructor:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(echo()));
timer->start(990);
```

Slot. It is just example, you should provide your specific code.

```
void MainWindow::echo()
{
    intervalSec = intervalSec - 1;
    if (intervalSec == -1)
    {
        intervalSec = 60 - 1;
        //time is up
    }
    int min,sec;
    min = intervalSec/60;
    sec = intervalSec%60;

    ui->lcdNumber->display(QString::number(min)+":"+QString::number(sec));

}
```

You can use `QLabel` to show time or use more beautiful widget `QLCDNumber` as I show in example. You can easily achieve next beautiful result(something like this):

[image]

Don't think that my way of calculating time is the best. I used variable, but you can use special class `QTime`.

[QLCDNumber](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlcdnumber.html), [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html)

Comment: hey Chernobyl , thank you so much , i had no idea QT had this time library :S 
this is really helpful 
let me get back to some coding and i'll post it back how it worked for my requirements :)
p.s i was searching purely how to make timer using c++ libraries and some related articles got me into multitasking and miltithreading concept of which i have no knowledge

Comment: @user3812696 You are welcome. If you work in Qt, first of all check Qt documentation, because Qt is cross-platform and documentation contains a lot of useful information. For example, timer written with clear WinAPI, will not work on Linux and so on.

Comment: @ Chernobyl , i got you ... :)